# Update the Rank 2 values based on Rank1 value column data

Tags: sql-server-2012, ranking

Data present in the table is as below:

Query:
select id, actv_ind, valid_from, valid_to, rnk from #ABC

[image]

Expected Data is as below:
I want to have the Valid_from date of Rank 2 records to be set as (Valid_from date of Rnk 1 record - 1)

Query tried:

```sql
select t1.id, t1.actv_ind, t1.rnk, case when t1.rnk >1 then t1.valid_from end VF1, case when t2.rnk > 1 then t1.valid_from - 1 end VF2
from #ABC t1
inner join #ABC t2
on t1.id = t2.id
and t1.actv_ind = t2.actv_ind
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `LAG`:

```sql
SELECT mtrl_id,
       actv_ind,
       rnk
       LAG(DATEADD(DAY, -1, valid_from),1,valid_from) OVER (PARTITION BY mtrl_id ORDER BY Rank) AS valid_from,
       valid_to
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. I am getting the date as same as valid_from date of an active record. I would need it to day -1.

Comment: Simple fix, change the first refernce to `valid_from` to `DATEADD(DAY, -1, valid_from)`